# Setting distance between two UITextFields in storyboard

Tags: xcode5

I am using storyboard and using the Auto-Layout in storyboard and placing UITextFields (for that matter, other elements as well) one after the other (one below the other).

I want to make sure that the distance between two textfields are the same. I could drag the textfields in the storyboard unless it looks perfect to me - but I want to be pixel-perfect everywhere.

How can I set the distance between two UI elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using storyboards again.

1. Select the UITextField in the storyboard.
2. Click on "Pin" option at the bottom of the storyboard.
3. Select the bottom vertical spacing in "Add New Constraints". This will become bold as opposed to others which will be dotted.
4. Click on "Add Constraint"
5. Select the bottom vertical constraint that appears on the bottom of the UITextField.
6. In the attributes window, change the value of "Constant".

[image]